# This report needs to take the last 10 recordings per component, get the average of those 10 and then display it as 1 row/record

Tags: sql-server

Sample Data

[image: Data]

This is my current query but as soon as I add my capturedDateTime and IsOutOfSpec fields then it returns multiple records which it should not.

```
SELECT Top 10 i.StockCode, i.LongDesc,
       AVG(c.PartWeightGram) AS Part_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.SprueWeightGram) AS Sprue_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.TolerancePercentage) AS Tolerance_Average, 
       AVG(c.BomWeightKG * 1000) AS Bom_Weight_Average,
       AVG(c.PartWeightGram + (c.SprueWeightGram / 2)) - (c.BomWeightKG)  AS Variance_To_Syspro_Average, 
       AVG((((((c.PartWeightGram + c.SprueWeightGram  / 2))) - (c.BomWeightKG * 1000)) / (c.BomWeightKG * 1000))  * 100) AS VarianceToSysproPct
FROM [Mercury].[EncoreCompanyA].dbo.InvMaster i CROSS APPLY 
     (SELECT TOP (10) c.*
      FROM tblComponentWeightCheck c 
      WHERE c.StockCode = i.StockCode
      ORDER BY c.CapturedDateTime DESC
     ) c
WHERE i.StockCode = '000-256966-020' AND Deleted = 'False'
GROUP BY i.StockCode, i.LongDesc, c.BomWeightKG
ORDER BY i.StockCode DESC;
```

Comment: Please post picture like text.

Comment: `as soon as I add my capturedDateTime and IsOutOfSpec fields` to where do you add it? If the `group by` clause then yes, that is what will happen. What do you expect to see? Text not pictures please